# How can I create a Map with non-unique keys in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, dictionary

To interface with existing code, I am hoping to implement a Map with non-unique keys in JavaScript/TypeScript (for a web app in Angular).

I know that Maps in JavaScript/TypeScript enforce unique keys.  How can I implement a "non-unique" Map?

Creating an array of Key-Value objects does not work as the structure does not de-serialize from JSON in the correct shape for the existing consumer code.

For example, I am hoping to create something like the following structure:

```
vehicleOptions : NonUniqueMap<key: string, value: {color: string, isTowingCapable: boolean}>
{
  "Truck", { "Red", true },
  "Compact Sedan", { "Black", false },
  "Compact Sedan", { "Blue", false }
}
```

Comment: Use an array instead, which contains objects, eg `{ label: 'Truck', obj: { ... } }`. Note that your current `{ "Red", true }` is invalid syntax, key-value pairs need to be separated by colons, not commas

Comment: why don't use Array instead ?

Comment: It's not clear how you would use this data structure. For example, why do you expect to get back when you use the key `Compact Sedan` on your object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't.

You can create a unique map.
When you have two same keys, you can store it as:

```
const map = {
    "Truck": [{ "Red": true }],
    "Compact Sedan": [{ "Black": false }, { "Blue": false }]
}
```

Then, when you get the value of `Compact Sedan`, you get an array.

So you can get the first/second value:

```
map["Compact Sedan"][0]; // { "Black": false }
map["Compact Sedan"][1]; // { "Blue": false }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this function to create uniqMap with List values:

```
function getBucketMap<T>(array: T[], uniqueProperty: string = 'id'): Map<any, T[]> {
    return array
    .filter(value => value)
    .reduce((bucketMap: Map<any, T[]>, item: T) => {
        const list = [item];

        if (bucketMap.has(item[uniqueProperty])) {
            list.push(...bucketMap.get(item[uniqueProperty]));
        }
        bucketMap.set(item[uniqueProperty], list);

        return bucketMap;

     }, new Map<any, T[]>());
}
```

so you could pass an array of cars and pass and uniq property like this:

```
const cars = [
  {
    type: 'Truck',
    info: {
        'black': true
    } 
  },
  {
    type: 'Truck',
    info: {
        'black': true
    } 
  },
  {
    type: 'Compact Sedan',
    info: {
        'blue': false
    } 
  },
];

const carsMap = getBucketMap(cars, 'type');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can abuse the Pass By Reference feature of JS here. Objects are passed by reference, so two different objects with same property would still be unique.
Consider the below example :

```
function function_key(a,b){
this.a = a;
this.b = b;
}
function function_val(c,d,e){
this.c = c;
this.d = d;
this.e = e;
}
var myMapName = new Map();
myMapName.set(new function_key('a','b'),new function_val('c','d','e'));
myMapName.set(new function_key('a','b'),new function_val('c','d','e'));
myMapName.set(new function_key('a','b'),new function_val('c','d','e'));
myMapName.set(new function_key('a','b'),new function_val('c','d','e'));
myMapName.set(new function_key('a','b'),new function_val('c','d','e'));
console.log(myMapName);
```

[Map seems DRUNK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTKXN.png)